The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked
I have an app that uses the entity framework. I have 2 DB contexts, one for the live sql database and another using InMemory for users to demo the site without changing the live db. The problem is when I add new entries to a table, the 2nd time I try I get this error.
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I'm configuring the DB contexts like this
        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options =>    
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        var databaseName = new Guid().ToString();
        services.AddDbContext<DemoDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

I'm also using AsNoTracking when getting data for the demo user
public IEnumerable<Ticket> GetTicketsForUserRole(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return _demoDbContext.Ticket.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(ticket => ticket.Author)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.Priority)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.State)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.Project)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.Type)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.AssignedUser)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.Comments)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.User)
            .Include(ticket => ticket.Attachments)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.User);
    }

I don't get the error when using the normal login and appDbContext.
This is where the issue occurs
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddComment(TicketsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(viewModel.TicketId != null)
        {
            var applicationUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var roleObject = _roleFactory.GetRole(applicationUser);

            var ticket = roleObject.GetTicketsForUserRole(applicationUser)
                .First(t => t.Id == viewModel.TicketId);

            viewModel.Ticket = ticket;

            var comment = new Comment
            {
                Date = DateAndTime.Now,
                TextComment = viewModel.TextComment,
                User = applicationUser
            };

            ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
            roleObject.UpdateTicket(ticket);

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = viewModel.Ticket.Id });
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

When I add the first comment it's ok, then I get the error when adding a second.
I am updating the ticket correctly?
public void UpdateTicket(Ticket ticket)
{
    _demoDbContext.Ticket.Update(ticket);
    _demoDbContext.SaveChanges();
}

If I remove AsNoTracking() I get the following error when adding the first Comment
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 63940036-1c2c-4f8c-8db7-d55f79ce40aaS ystem.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)

Update:
I can fix the error by removing the Application User Property from the Comment Table.
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Post Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{ 0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm }")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TextComment { get; set; }
}

This is not ideal as I would like to link the users to their comments.

No, If you want to update something, do not use AsNoTracking. If object is tracked DO NOT calll Update method. EF tracks changes automatically. And do you really need to load so many details for the ticket?

When I remove AsNoTracking I get an error when adding the first Comment "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 63940036-1c2c-4f8c-8db7-d55f79ce40aa
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)"
This key is the Id of the DemoAdmin user, not the id of the comment.

Make GetTicketsForUserRole returning IQueryable. Do not load half of the database.

When I remove the Include<>s I get this error in the razor page...System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
YetAnotherBugTracker.Models.Ticket.Priority.get returned null.

I do not force you to remove Include. return IQueryable instead of IEnumerable. You have loaded ALL Tickets from database with all details.

Ok, thank you I'll do that.
It still doesn't stop the error for occuring though.

Include in question exception call stack when you remove AsNoTracking.
